# Cmake override find_package for a given target

Tags: cmake

We have a CMakeLists.txt that links (for instance) opencv to our various binaries. This is done as follow:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc highgui contrib) 
target_link_library(XXX opencv_core)
```

We also would like to allow the person building the library to provide its own opencv library. It seems that this could be done setting -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to the right path.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=".../mybuild/include;.../mybuild/lib" .
```

However I would like to be sure the library used is exactly the one specified by the client (i.e. if there is nothing in /mybuild/lib the configuration fails).

How can I allow somebody building the library to override the library used ? (if nothing is specified it should fall back to find_package-s)

Comment: I don't quite undestand: Do you want to **allow** user (who builds your package) to specify its own library installation (OpenCV in your case), or to **disallow** that? Which case is "general" and which one is "specific"?

Comment: I would like to allow the user to specify its own library (for example its own patched version of opencv). if not specified, I would like to keep the find_package-s.

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` when call `cmake` is the **right way** for a user to specify its own library. So, what is a problem?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I would like the configuration (cmake) to fail, if the provided library is not found. For me CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is just a hint, it will still try to find the library on the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## In short

1. If the package provides `<package>Config.cmake` script, user may specify `<package>_DIR` CMake variable for locate this script.

   Searching other places in that case may be disabled with *NO_DEFAULT_PATH* option for `find_package()`.
2. If a package is searched with `Find<package>.cmake` script, there is no (generic) way for disable searching other places if user provides hint variable but it is wrong.

## Explanations

Firstly, `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` provides *additional installation tree for all packages*. As this variable is applied to **all** `find_package()` calls, it is not wise to *require all packages* to be found under it.

When talk about the ways for specify installation directory for **specific package**, we need to distinguish two kinds of "find" scripts:

1. `<package>Config.cmake` (or some alternative names, see [find_package documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html)).

   These scripts are shipped with the packages themselves. And there is **universal way** for user to specify location of such packages: CMake variable `<package>_DIR`, which should point to the directory with `*Config.cmake` script.

   While default behaviour of `find_package()` is treating `<package>_DIR` variable as an *additional* hint, passing *NO_DEFAULT_PATH* option disables all implicit paths:

   ```
   if(<package>_DIR) # Variable is set by the user or by previous `cmake` run.
       # Search only under given directory.
       find_package(<package> NO_DEFAULT_PATH) 
   else()
       # Search everywhere (as documented for 'find_package').
       find_package(<package>) 
   endif()
   ```
2. `Find<package>.cmake`.

   This script either is shipped with CMake or should be shipped with the project.

   Most of such scripts allows to hint about package location with variable (CMake or environment one) like `<package>_DIR`, `<package>_ROOT` or so.

   However, almost all such scripts treat hint variable only as *additional search place*, so if variable is set to wrong value, they simply ignore it. And without modifying the script you cannot change that behavior.

Comment: Great answer, in that is seems the best approach for what's available. The problem is that this requires modification of the script that calls `find_package`. It's less helpful for transitive dependencies or generally for scripts you don't own.  What's really needed is a way for the _client_ to force/override specific locations in a standard way, but without requiring any changes to existing scripts, _and_ that works uniformly for Module/Config modes. (And keeping the same semantics asked in the question, in opposition to the looser approach of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or just setting `*_DIR`).